# Prevent UIWebView from displaying "web page not available"

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I want to know how to prevent the "web page not found" error in an iOS app when we use UIWebView which allows our website to be viewable in an iOS app.

Comment: Are you using `UIWebViewDelegate`? You could instead hide the webview itself on [didFailLoadWithError](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwebviewdelegate/1617970-webview).

Comment: no i am not but tell me how to use it if you can give me some code